# Z-index & Tooltips in Tables (DOM order of appearance)

Tags: html, css, debugging, z-index

Ok, so I'm trying to override z-index of all parent-level divs / elements on tooltips and it's proving difficult with the table setup that I need to use.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/5/

In the preceding JS Fiddle, hovering the bottom row (#3), you'll se that the tooltip covers the word "Content" from row #2 when hovered.  This is because the Z-index is inheriting from the respective parents (I think) and therefore equal.  As a result, the stack order is determined by the order of appearance within the DOM itself.  For this reason, the tooltip covers any content in the row above it and fails to cover any content in the row below it.

I'm looking for a solution and I know it may be impossible, but I'm just hoping I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this particular Z-index issue cannot be circumvented.  The answer which I discussed with @r3bel extensively did not account for my particular use case and the JS Fiddle is not quite a correct solution.

I ended up using Twitter Bootstrap's `bootstrap-popover.js` plugin which appends the popover to the `<body>` dynamically ensuring that it's position in the z-index stack is respected.

Answer (score 1):

so why don't you just leave away the z-index property for td elements?

[edited version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/4/)

i think that is what you wanted to get, right? :)

btw: "The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.", so you maybe might not want to use position relative at the td element but use a child div in the td element or something similar to that instead :)

I added a div with position: relative into the first row, that you can see the difference (if you use e.g. the latest firefox)

Comment: Good point @r3bel.  Apologies for this, but I was lazy and failed to completely breakdown the issue.  I actually have multiple divs inside each `<td>` and some of those divs are `postion: relative` and some are `position: absolute`, both of which have tooltips. Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/5/ ... Needless to say, it's a long story.  It's a calendar with blocks for events that span multiple days.

Comment: you have to add at least one surrounding "position:relative" div in each td element, since all "position:absolute" elements will be oriented on the table tag otherwise, so change your parent's div position to absolute and you are done (i guess.. ^^): [http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/6/)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you shortened the tooltip so the issue went away, but it was never solved.  I changed only the height of the tooltip in the updated JS Fiddle and got this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/8/.

Pretty sure what I need to do is impossible, such a weird feeling because that pretty much never happens in CSS.

Comment: seems like you want to add z-index to each field :P... just leave it away and it works: [http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9H4U/10/)